# Question about meaning of "cultures the world" & "over enjoy" in this passage

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Diet fads come and go so quickly that many of them are gone before we’ve really even learned what they are. One diet that has remained constant at the forefront, however, is tea. **Cultures the world over enjoy teas** in a variety of different ways. Recently, the health benefits of tea have become a common topic of discussion, and many health companies are boasting a number of diet products that use tea as a main ingredient.

Could you simplify the highlited part in simple English,please?
When saying **cultures the world...** , does it mean **all cultures and people in the world enjoy tea a lot** ?

Answer (score 4):

You're actually trying to break the expression in the wrong place.

> "the world over" = "all over the world"

Over isn't actually modifying enjoy. We don't all drink TOO much tea.

That said, I'd rephrase it as

> All over the world, cultures enjoy teas...

Answer (score 1):

Not quite - it means various (not necessarily all) cultures all over the world enjoy tea.

Comment: -Thanks, should we read over and enjoy together to mean enjoy a lot ?

Comment: No, you read "world over" together to mean the whole world.